# One template class (name) for both compile-time and runtime array with little code duplication

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Is there a way to construct a template class that functions as both a compile and runtime array (much like the C89 constant size array and the same C99 variable length array) which allows for logical semantics (one template parameter for the variable length array, two for the fixed length, much like `std::array`).

To top it off, I'd like to prevent code duplication between the two cases, as most functions are identical between the two cases. Is there a way to use `constexpr` or `enable_if` to achieve this?

Comment: IIUC, you want a statically allocated `std::vector` that can store a variable number of elements, but with a compile time limit for its maximum size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Eigen linear algebra library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) did this exact thing, with C++03 only. Their matrices have compile-time sizes with a special value (`Eigen::Dynamic`) indicating that the size should be chosen at runtime. Through template specialization, the storage is realized.

Example:

```
template <typename Type,int N>
class Array {
   Type data[N];
};

template <typename Type>
class Array<Type,Dynamic> {
   boost::scoped_array<Type> data;
};
```

Comment: You don't need template specialization, that would just create unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Specialize only the storage, and you have very little duplication. The key insight is that the array operations are independent of the storage model.

Comment: Still it is one extra level of unneeded indirection.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: The Eigen library gets excellent mileage from this indirection.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, the Eigen developers are geniuses. I get it. Again, the indirection is unnecessary and just creates code duplication. That doesn't mean that this solution won't work, it's just unnecessary complex.

Comment: This specialization is the kind of code duplication I want to avoid. Is there no other trick possible using perhaps newer C++11 features or SFINAE?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : What "indirection" are you even talking about? I see none here.

Comment: @iljarn Of course you don't see any indirection. This code is the extra indirection level that isn't needed.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : "*it is one extra level of unneeded indirection*", "*the indirection is unnecessary*", "*Of course you don't see any indirection*" -- uh, okay.

Comment: @rubenvb: You say this is the type of duplication you want to avoid.  thiton has already mentioned that you should only use this for the storage.  Are you still thinking you need to duplicate the access to the storage?  Or do you have some other duplication concern?  Because you don't need any more duplication than this - which is the minimal you need to specify two different types.  You just use a traits class and in your class to define the type as above.  Then in your class you use `StorageTraits<StorageType>::type data;` to define your member data.  Or c++11's templated aliases...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem. Have the size parameter with a default value -1, and just make a static if (type chooser) in the class to choose a static array, or a dynamic array.

The internal logic should be most identical, different parts can be easily resolved using overloading.

The usage then would be:

```
array<int> x; /* dynamic array */
array<int,10> y; /* static array */
```

Comment: What do you mean by `static if` exactly? A real `if` statement in the constructor?

Comment: @rubenvb Just to select between the two types. You can use `enable_if` from boost, or just use type selector like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1037357/211659